# Configure caddy (Caddyfile) for custom domain

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, caddy, caddyfile

I'm trying to configure the Caddyfile to allow accessing my website build on an Azure virtual machine via custom domain.

Here is my Caddyfile:

DOMAIN_NAME=azuredomain.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:80

```
{$DOMAIN_NAME} {
  # HTTPS options:
  # tls {$TLS_EMAIL}

  # Test HTTPS setup
  # tls {$TLS_EMAIL} {
  #   ca https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
  # }

  # Removing some headers for improved security:
  header / -Server

  # Serves static files, should be the same as `STATIC_ROOT` setting:
  root /var/www/django

  # Serving dynamic requests:
  proxy / django:8000 {
    except /static /media
    transparent
    websocket
  }

  # Allows to use `.gz` files when available:
  gzip

  # Logs:
  log stdout
  errors stdout
}
```

I have created 2 CNAME in my custom domain, which is subdomain.domain.com:

```
www.subdomain.domain.com.   600 CNAME   
azuredomain.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
 
subdomain.domain.com.   600 CNAME   
azuredomain.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
```

I can access the website from azuredomain.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com, but not from my custom domain: subdomain.domain.com

The error I get is:

> 404 Site subdomain.domain.com is not served on this interface

```
nslookup subdomain.domain.com
```

Gives:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
subdomain.domain.com       canonical name = azuredomain.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
Name:   azuredomain.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
Address: <I have hidden the address for privacy concenrs>
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. How can I access the website build on azure from my custom domain?